# Informix "load" command is not working in Python pyodbc

Tags: python, informix, pyodbc

We are writing a utility to load data into Informix DB.

Our utility is written in Python and we are using pyodbc package to connect and execute the SQLs.

The select and insert queries are working fine.

However, the sql

> "load from input_file delimiter '|' insert into table"

is failing with below error.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred. (-201) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Whether pyodbc is not supporting "load" command in Informix?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [J_S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7761106/j-s) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49264208/15168), the `LOAD` command is a pseudo-SQL command implemented by front-end tools; it is not implemented by the database server.

There are a number of other related commands with the same property:

- `LOAD`
- `UNLOAD`
- `OUTPUT`
- `INFO`

One of the complicating factors for `LOAD` is that the file name is specified by the client on the local machine but the contents of the file may have to be transferred over the network to where the database server resides.  That is not an insuperable problem; similar issues can arise with BLOB and CLOB files, and have been overcome.

These operations are all implemented by ISQL and DB-Access (and by tools such as my [SQLCMD](http://members.iiug.org/software/index_ESQLC.html) — you may have to register to download it, but registration is free and the email load is not onerous).

Comment: Dont we have a python library which does this operation, similar to sqlcmd? I was under the assumption that pyodbc is generic and that is why it wont support and any Informix specific python lib will have this implemented.

Comment: If it was implemented, it would be by someone who knows enough about pyodbc to know how to do that reliably, and who provides the code.  There's the file reading (not too complex), the field splitting, the type management (BYTE and TEXT blobs are tricky; most of the rest are manageable, but BLOB and CLOB also present some issues), and then the basic insertion (which is the least complex part).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, we modified the script to do the "insert" instead of "load"

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, 'LOAD from ...' (and 'UNLOAD TO ...') only works with DBACCESS and ISQL. None of the client APIs (ODBC/JDBC/.NET) support those commands.

Comment: Thank you J_S for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

How about using external tables to load data ?
INSERT INTO target1 SELECT * FROM ext1;

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2068.htm

Comment: Thank you for the comment Nagaraju, this was something new to me.